# Erro ao construir: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

Gostaria de saber como faço para tirar esse erro quando tento criar um novo app. O erro é o seguinte: ele carrega tudo certo, mas quando ele vai carregar o Gradle ele dá erro e a tela fica infinitamente no "Waiting for build to finish". No *Gradle Console* está escrito o seguinte:

> ```
> Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_5" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\JP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
>         at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:196)
>         at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
>         at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Sabem como resolver? (Obs: Firewall já foi desligado)

Comment: Isso acontece com todo projeto novo ou só esse?

Comment: Com todo projeto